# CSS3 with linear gradient for two directions

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a header in my website which currently use a linear gradient to move from one color to the other. This is the CSS:

```
#top-header {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(100%, #be2e26), color-stop(20%, #be2e26), color-stop(20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0)), color-stop(20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #be2e26 100%, #be2e26 40%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 100) 100%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 100) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #be2e26 30%, #be2e26 20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 50%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#be2e26', endColorstr='#be2e26', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

It starts from the left and slightly change the color to the right. I want to do the same thing from the right at the same time. I tried to include the following, but it keeps only one of the two lines:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #be2e26 30%, #be2e26 20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 50%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to left, #be2e26 30%, #be2e26 20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 50%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 100%);
```

It keeps only the second. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add more `linear-gradient`s by separating them with a comma `,`.

```
background: <linear-gradient>, <linear-gradient>,...
```

---

```css
#top-header {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 99999;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(100%, #be2e26), color-stop(20%, #be2e26), color-stop(20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0)), color-stop(20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0))), -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, top top, color-stop(100%, #be2e26), color-stop(20%, #be2e26), color-stop(20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0)), color-stop(20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #be2e26 100%, #be2e26 40%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 100) 100%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 100) 100%), linear-gradient(to left, #be2e26 30%, #be2e26 20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 50%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #be2e26 30%, #be2e26 20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 50%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 100%), linear-gradient(to left, #be2e26 30%, #be2e26 20%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 50%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#be2e26', endColorstr='#be2e26', GradientType=1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<header id="top-header"></header>
```

Comment: what about use linear-gradient for bottom and right.?, i want use 3 color for my background 1 on top and 2 in bottom.?