# Adding horizontal and vertical fading gradients on an element

Tags: css, linear-gradients

Is there a way to have a background gradient from left to right, dark red to light red (just as an example), but also at the same time a fade from top 100% opacity to bottom 0% opacity?

It's not the same as a diagonal gradient, it's a gradient with color on X axis and transparency on Y axis.

I've been trying to see if I can manage, but I can't figure out a way to do it.

[EDIT]

This is a picture of what I have. It's just one of bootstrap's templates.

As you can see, I have a gradient from left (darker red) to right (lighter red).

I would also like this entire element to fade to white at the bottom, so that the cutoff for this section is not sudden, but gradual.

[image: Example 1]

As you can see here, going with the diagonal solution, the edge on the left side is still very sharp. What I want is for the entire bottom side to fade to white, that is, a transparency gradient on the Y axis, while I still have the left to right color gradient on the X axis.

[image: Example 2]

Comment: possible dubplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052238/css3-with-linear-gradient-for-two-directions not sure if that combines them or just does 2 seperate

Comment: Can you post a picture of expected result? It is possible but I am not sure about the expected result.

Comment: Proably a radial gradient of some kind...or `conical`.

Comment: Hard to do an expected result, I'm not good at photohop to create an image. Give me a minute.

Comment: I added a couple of examples of what I have, and what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple gradient to simulate this:

```css
body {
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to top,rgba(255,255,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0)),
   linear-gradient(to right,black,white);
}
```

Comment: This one comes closest to what I want to achieve. Thank you very much, I didn't know it was possible to concatenate gradients.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a radial gradient from one corner

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

div {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 10vh auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at left top, rgba(139, 0, 0, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```